# Encode a codepoint

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding

I have a Unicode codepoint, which could be *anything*: possibly ASCII, possibly something in the BMP, and possibly an exotic emoji such as U+1F612.

I expected there would be an easy way to take a codepoint and encode it into a byte array, but I can't find a simple way. I can turn it into a String, and then encode it, but that is a round-about way involving first encoding it to UTF-16 and then re-encoding it to the required encoding. I'd like to encode it directly to bytes.

```
public static byte[] encodeCodePoint(int codePoint, Charset charset) {
    // Surely there's got to be a better way than this:
    return new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(codePoint).toString().getBytes(charset);
}
```

Comment: Since `CharsetEncoder` only deals in `char` (and multiple thereof), I'm afraid you won't find a more direct way. You can avoid building a `String`, but you'll need some kind of `CharSequence` (such as a `CharBuffer`). Is the final goal **really** to encode *individual* codepoints and not just a whole stream of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no way to avoid using UTF-16, since Java uses UTF-16 for text data, and that is what the charset convertors are designed for. But, that doesn't mean you have to use a `String` for the UTF-16 data:

```java
public static byte[] encodeCodePoint(int codePoint, Charset charset) {
    char[] chars = Character.toChars(codePoint);
    CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.wrap(chars);
    ByteBuffer buff = charset.encode(cb);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buff.remaining()];
    buff.get(bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I believe this might not always work, as the array is the allocated array and may in some cases be bigger than the actual data inside it.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why `encode()` would return a `ByteBuffer` that is larger than the actual output. And every example I have seen assumes that `encode().array()` is the proper length. But whatever, you can easily account for this, if needed. I have updated my answer to show how.

Comment: Try, for example, `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(Character.toChars(0x1F612)))`. You'll get a ByteBuffer with a limit of 4 and a capacity of 5. The array() method returns the full backing array, with 5 elements, only 4 of which are used, the last one being 0. So your "alternative" is in fact the only option.